# Can't enable TUN/TAP on VPS

Tags: centos, vpn, openvpn, vps, virtuozzo

I'm desperately looking for a way to enable TUN/TAP on a VPS in order to use an OpenVPN client. The VPS is based on Parallels Virtuozzo. I've been reading a ton of tutorials and forum topics, and here is the output I'm getting with the commands I often see :

```
lsmod | grep tun
(no output)

modprobe tun
FATAL: Module tun not found.
```

When I try to run the client, here is what I get at some point :

```
ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
```

The server is running CentOS 6.7. Let me know if there is anything other piece of information I need to provide.

UPDATE : I found out that only the host should be able to help me by enabling TUN/TAP on the container. However, they don't "offer this feature" for some reason. I found a similar case here : http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1470090
Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you tag this virtuozzo if it is not? If it _is_, then you need to follow the directions in the linked answer.

Comment: Then what kind of virtualisation instead? Check with `sudo virt-what` and update your question please.

Comment: @HBruijn Sorry, my bad it is an OpenVZ installation indeed, but the host provider can't enable TUN/TAP for some reason. I found a similar case here : http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1470090 Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelHampton You are right, I'm updating my post.

Comment: In that case your only option is to move to another provider.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is it possible to create a tun device with tunctl?

Comment: No, your **only** option is to switch to another provider. Please don't make me repeat myself again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for your replies. I have two more questions : I'm having a hard time understanding what tunctl is used for. The 2nd question is what other option do I have to be anonymous. We can rule out Tor. Feel free to send any relevant links. Thanks again.